# Congruence modulo $n$ forms an equivalence class

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am learning about equivalence classes, and I learned that congruence modulo $n$ forms an equivalence relation. In the proof below, I didn't understand how at the very end of the second picture they said "we assumed a result known as the division algorithm" because no where in their proof did it look like they used it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The book says "division algorithm" not "euclidean algorithm".

Answer (score 1):

The [Division algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division) is the theorem that states when you divide $n$ by $m$ (both integers, and $m>0$), you get a unique quotient and remainder, and the remainder is between $0$ and $m-1$.

This was used in determining that there were three equivalence classes modulo $3$.  More generally, there are $m$ equivalence classes modulo $m$.

Comment: They used it since each integer has a remainder from $0$ to $n-1$ modulo $n$?